# reading from a flatfile without outputting the entire thing

Tags: c, database, file, structure, database-scan

Ok, here is a function that will read a file and paste the values on screen, however, i want to be able to printf a specific row. Now, should i create a loop that printf the entire file but does a `system("cls");` everytime datacount is not equal to the user input, or is there a better way of doing this?

```
void NameSelect(void)
{
     //Screen refresh
    DataCount=1;

    fFn=fopen("PDfirstN.txt","r"); //Opens student usernames
    fscanf(fFn,"%16[^\n]%*c", stockF[DataCount].def); //Scans first line
    fLn=fopen("PDlastN.txt","r"); //Opens student passwords
    fscanf(fLn,"%16[^\n]%*c", stockL[DataCount].def2); //scans first line

    do
    {  
        printf("%d.",  DataCount);                                             
        printf(" %s",  stockF[DataCount].def); 
        printf(" %s",  stockL[DataCount].def2);

        DataCount=DataCount+1; //Next line counter
        fscanf(fFn,    "%16[^\n]%*c", stockF[DataCount].def); //Scans next line
        fscanf(fLn,    "%16[^\n]%*c", stockL[DataCount].def2);
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(!feof(fFn)); //While there accounts in user name file

    fclose(fFn);
    fclose(fLn);
}
```

Comment: How about just printing the specified index, no loop at all? Like e.g. `printf("%d. %s %s\n", 2, stockF[2].def, stockL[2].def2);`

Comment: Wait, what? that's exactly what i did?, the [2] was the count variable

Comment: Printing it *outside* the loop I mean. This is, IMO, a pretty stupid question. You have a loop, you print in the loop, but you don't want to print in the loop. What would the obvious solution be? *Not* to print in the loop. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't call printf, if you don't want to display anything.

```
do
{  
    if (DataCount == DATA_COUNT_I_WANT) {
        printf("%d.",  DataCount);                                             
        printf(" %s",  stockF[DataCount].def); 
        printf(" %s",  stockL[DataCount].def2);
        printf("\n");
    }

    DataCount=DataCount+1; //Next line counter
    fscanf(fFn,    "%16[^\n]%*c", stockF[DataCount].def); //Scans next line
    fscanf(fLn,    "%16[^\n]%*c", stockL[DataCount].def2);        
}
while(!feof(fFn)); //While there accounts in user name file
```